# Excel Highlight Second Entry within a Range of Cells

Tags: excel, cell, highlight, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight the cell of a second entry (and beyond) within a range of cells. I am tyring to implement this feature in my attendence tracking.

For example, in the image below, I have "Peter", "John" and "Tom". If there are only one person who is absent, I do not need to highlight anything, as shown below.

[image]

However, if either "Tom" or "John" is the second person to be entered as "Not in" (absent), I want to highlight the cells, as shown below.

[image]

Finally, if the last person left is also absent, I would like to highlight it as well, like below image

[image]

The values in Column C is not restricted to these phrases ("Absent","Away","Not in").

From another point of view, I want to highlight the second and the later entries within a range of cells. Is there a way to implement such feature without using VBA or macro? Can it be donne using conditional formating?

Please advise. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Worksheet_Change event to add a timestamp to a helper column. In my case, I added it to column D:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = Range("C3:C9")
    If Not Application.Intersect(myrange, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
            Else
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Then use conditional formatting on column C using something like this:

```
=$D3>=SMALL($D$3:$D$9,2)
```

This will highlight any rows where the the timestamp is greater than the second smallest timestamp (ignoring blanks).

Here's an example of it in action. For illustration purposes, I put the order I typed things in column C rather than "Absent", "Not Here", etc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, I am also consider the case where the first entry is not at cell C2 (Peter), it can be C3 (first entry), then C2 (second entry) or C4 (first entry), then C2 (second entry). Is it possible to do it no matter which cell is being filled in first? Thanks!

Comment: So you're asking to highlight based on the time the entry is made, not based on it's row position? Just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, based on the time the entry is made. Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking whether multiple conditional formating rules would work, but i could not get my head around it.

Comment: Conditional formatting is probably not your answer then. If you try to use the `Now()` function to add a timestamp it's going to constantly re-evaluate. There are methods for avoiding that (https://howtoexcelatexcel.com/blog/create-a-timestamp-in-excel-with-formulas/), but it involves circular referencing which I try to avoid. You're probably going to need a VBA solution.

Comment: @TommyYip I updated my answer now that I understand what you're looking for.